# How to replace an image by another by clicking a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I started iOS development a few days ago and got stopped by the following problem: image does not change by clicking. The former image disappears.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
- (IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize imgView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animal_3.png"];
    [imgView setImage: img];}
@end
```

Comment: Was `changeImage:` called?

Comment: Maybe the image fails to load and `img` is nil? Is the image animal_3.png included in the target? It should be listed either in the Xcode project or in your Images.xcasset and when you select it you need to see a tick under "Target Membership"

Comment: Did you connect both the `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` in the storyboard? As @TimVermeulen said, if `changeImage:` wasn't called, it is probably not connected. And, if `imgView` is nil it, also, is not wired up to the storyboard/xib.

Comment: The image ist included in "Supporting Files". The Connection Editor shows imgView as an outlet and changeImage as an action.

Answer (score 0):

As the image is disappearing when you set it i can assume that your outlets & actions are correctly defined.

The new image "animal_3.png" may not exist. Please ensure that it has been properly added to the images.xcassets and is named correctly. Also be sure that the images.xcassets is included in the targets bundle resources (Project > Select correct target > Build Phases > Ensure images.xcassets is included in the copy bundle resources list, if not add it).

If you are unsure how to debug and see if the image is set. 
Please try this code to confirm that the image is actually being loaded properly.

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animal_3.png"];
    if (image)
    {
        NSLog(@"Image exists");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NO IMAGE");
    }
```

[Adding Images using xcassets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/AddingImages.html)

Screenshot of confirming that the xcassets file is added to the build phases (Xcode 7.2):
[image]

Comment: Can't find "Project > Select correct target > Build Phases > ..." in Xcode 7.

Comment: "Adding Images using Xcassets" looks different. I verified, images are loaded, imgView and changeImg (Action) are visible in the Connection Editor.

Comment: Please see updated answer to confirm that the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

if the former image disappears, that's mean your "animal_3.png" image does not exist. check the name of the image may be.

Comment: After reading the code dozen times if found a missing "s" in the file name. Thank you all!

Comment: could you approved like correct answer please. thanks :)